# What is the molecular mechanism of odorant transduction signaling pathway?

Tags: molecular-biology, pathway, odour

I have read a few papers on the topic of odorant signaling pathway. The following papers are listed as examples. However, I found that there is not a clear pathway representation of the odorant signaling pathway, through which the involved genes and regulations should be known. Is there any paper I have missed?

- Menzel, R. and P. Benjamin (2013). Invertebrate learning and memory,
  Academic Press.
- Leal WS: Odorant reception in insects: roles of
  receptors, binding proteins, and degrading enzymes. Annu Rev Entomol
  2013, 58:373-391.
- Kaupp, U. B. (2010). "Olfactory signalling in
  vertebrates and insects: differences and commonalities." Nat Rev
  Neurosci 11(3): 188-200.
- Vosshall, L. B. and R. F. Stocker (2007).
  "Molecular architecture of smell and taste in Drosophila." Annu Rev
  Neurosci 30: 505-533.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Information available on this is huge. I will pin point main points. Generally this signalling will involve four components viz. receptors, transduction machinery, perireceptor processes and downstream processing of chemosensory information.

**Receptors**
First step is to receive signal (here odorant or chemicals). Following figure shows comparison between primary chemoreceptor neurons in vertebrates, insects, and nematodes.

[image]

These neurons constantly undergoes birth-maturation-death and process is [well studied](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-66880-7_2) in many model systems.

**Signal transduction**

After stimulus is received, it needs to be transfer inside cell for further processing. In this case, generally transduction happens via [GPCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G_protein%E2%80%93coupled_receptor) signalling. These neurons use two widely used signalling cascades. Following figure shows main components in this signalling ( (a):vertebrate olfactory receptor neurons (b): lobster olfactory receptor neurons),

[image]

**Perireceptor Processes**

These process are [important](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1694326) for receptor activation and transduction. They can be any type like mechanical or biochemical.

**Downstream processing**

There is huge information available at the level of pathway. Following figure represents main components in two model systems.

[image]

For finding genes, you have to search in specific part of this process (like [this](http://www.pnas.org/content/101/8/2584.full) is good example of receptor genes in human).

I would strongly recommend reading chapter 4 of "[The Senses](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/referenceworks/9780123708809#ancvol4) - Comprehensive Reference". **All above information** is taken from this book. Another good open source reference is [The Neurobiology of Olfaction](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK55980/), this reference has all things you need for *free*.

Comment: thank you for your comprehensive answer. I will peruse the references.